# Unique list of nodes in an edge-list

Tags: python, awk

I have a large edge list (~26 million) with first two columns as nodes and with a variable number of optional columns:

```
Node1    Node2    OptionalCol1    OptionalCol2   ...

Gene A    Gene D   --             --
Gene C    Gene F   --             --
Gene D    Gene C   --             --
Gene F    Gene A   --             --
```

I want a text file that will have a **non-redundant** list of nodes combining ***both*** the columns.
Output:

```
Gene A
Gene D
Gene C
Gene F
```

My python code:

```
file1 = open("input.txt", "r")
node_id = file1.readlines()
node_list=[]

for i in node_id:
    node_info=i.split()
    node_info[0]=node_info[0].strip()
    node_info[1]=node_info[1].strip()
    if node_info[0] not in node_list:
        node_list.append(node_info[0])
    if node_info[1] not in node_list:
        node_list.append(node_info[1])

print node_list
```

Is it possible to do this with awk ? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to produce a list of unique nodes from `Node1` and `Node2`?

Comment: yes, a unique list combining both columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the delimiter is a tab (`\t`). If it's a bunch of space (a bunch being more than one) instead of `-F"\t"` use: `-F"  +"`:

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'NR>2{a[$1];a[$2]}END{for(i in a)print i}' file
Gene A
Gene C
Gene D
Gene F
```

The output is not in any particular order but it could be. Explained:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '
NR>2 {           # starting on the third record
    a[$1]        # hash first...
    a[$2]        # and second columns
}
END {            # after all that hashing
    for(i in a)  # iterate whole hash
        print i  # and output
}' file
```

Comment: Dear James, could you pls take a look at my latest question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528957/script-to-work-with-coordinate-of-genes-file

Answer (score 1):

You could combine awk with sort unique:

```
$ awk '/Gene/ {print $1, $2; print $3, $4}' file | sort -u
Gene A
Gene C
Gene D
Gene F
```

Or if your columns are tab-separated:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '/Gene/ {print $1; print $2}' file | sort -u
Gene A
Gene C
Gene D
Gene F
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file is separated by tabs you can use this, but you can change the `sep` parameter to whatever your delimiter is.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', sep='\t', usecols=['Node1', 'Node2'])
node_list = np.concatenate((df['Node1'].unique(), df['Node2'].unique()))
```

When working with relational data, like your file looks, `pandas` is a very useful and quick tool that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `set()` in `python` like so:

```
file1=open("input.txt",'r')

lines = file1.read().split('\n')

all_nodes_as_string=' '.join(lines) #you can use '\t' here if that's what separates the nodes on each line

all_nodes_with_dupes = all_nodes_as_string.split(' ')

all_unique_nodes = set(all_nodes_with_dupes)
```