# Script to work with coordinate (of genes) file

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a variation table (**variation.txt**) which is a very big file. The first column in the **chromosome number** and the second column is the **position** of the variation. I have a second file **annotation.txt** which has a list of 37,000 genes (**1st column**), their chromosome number(**2nd column**), their start and end coordinates (**3rd column**), followed by some details

I have to assign the variations (based on chromosome number and its position) to the genes. First, it should look for the **matching chromosome number** in both files, and if that matches, the coordinate of the variation should be within (including) start and end position of the gene. I have attempted it in python but its **taking a long time**. Moreover, I want to have a modified output as shown below. Genes can have overlapping coordinates and a given variation can be part of multiple overlapping genes. Kindly help.

**variation.txt**

```
SL3.0ch02   702679  C   A   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
SL3.0ch01   711131  A   G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
SL3.0ch00   715124  G   A   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
SL3.0ch00   719289  C   T   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
SL3.0ch00   720926  A   C   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
SL3.0ch00   723860  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS     NONSYNONYMOUS   W/G     52  0   novel   DELETERIOUS (*WARNING! Low confidence)
SL3.0ch00   723867  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS     SYNONYMOUS  G/G     49  1   novel   TOLERATED
SL3.0ch00   723903  T   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS     SYNONYMOUS  G/G     37  1   novel   TOLERATED
```

**annotation.txt**

```
Solyc00g005000.3.1  SL3.0ch02   702600  702900  +   Eukaryotic aspartyl protease family protein
Solyc00g005040.3.1  SL3.0ch01   715100  715200  +   Potassium channel
Solyc00g005050.3.1  SL3.0ch00   715150  715300  -   UPF0664 stress-induced protein C29B12.11c
Solyc00g005060.1.1  SL3.0ch00   723741  724013  -   LOW QUALITY:Cyclin/Brf1-like TBP-binding protein
Solyc00g005080.2.1  SL3.0ch00   723800  723900  -   LOW QUALITY:Protein Ycf2
Solyc00g005084.1.1  SL3.0ch05   809593  813633  +   UDP-Glycosyltransferase superfamily protein
Solyc00g005090.1.1  SL3.0ch07   1061632 1061916 -   LOW QUALITY:DYNAMIN-like 1B
Solyc00g005092.1.1  SL3.0ch01   1127794 1144385 +   Serine/threonine phosphatase-like protein
Solyc00g005094.1.1  SL3.0ch00   1144958 1146952 -   Glucose-6-phosphate 1-dehydrogenase 3, chloroplastic
Solyc00g005096.1.1  SL3.0ch00   1734562 1736567 +   RWP-RK domain-containing protein
```

**Desired output:**

```
SL3.0ch02   702679  C   A   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Solyc00g005000.3.1  
SL3.0ch00   715124  G   A   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   Solyc00g005040.3.1  
SL3.0ch00   723860  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS NONSYNONYMOUS   W/G 52  0   novel   DELETERIOUS (*WARNING! Low confidence)  Solyc00g005060.1.1  
SL3.0ch00   723860  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS NONSYNONYMOUS   W/G 52  0   novel   DELETERIOUS (*WARNING! Low confidence)  Solyc00g005080.2.1  
SL3.0ch00   723867  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS SYNONYMOUS  G/G 49  1   novel   TOLERATED   Solyc00g005060.1.1  
SL3.0ch00   723867  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS SYNONYMOUS  G/G 49  1   novel   TOLERATED   Solyc00g005080.2.1  
SL3.0ch00   723903  T   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS SYNONYMOUS  G/G 37  1   novel   TOLERATED   Solyc00g005060.1.1
```

**Code:**

```
import re
file1 = open("variation", "r")
file2 = open("annotation.txt", "r")
probe_id = file1.read().splitlines()
loc_id = file2.read().splitlines()

for i in probe_id:
    i=i.rstrip()
    probe_info=i.split('\t')
    probe_info[1]=probe_info[1].strip()
    probe_info[0]=probe_info[0].strip()
    #print probe_info[1]
    gene_list=[]
    for j in loc_id:
        loc_info=j.split('\t')
        loc_info[2]=loc_info[2].strip()
        loc_info[3]=loc_info[3].strip()
        if loc_info[1]==probe_info[0]:
            if (int(probe_info[1]) >= int(loc_info[2])):
                 if (int(probe_info[1]) <=int(loc_info[3])):
                    gene_list.append(loc_info[0])
    if len(gene_list)!=0:
        print i+"\t"+str(gene_list)
```

**Current output:**

```
SL3.0ch02   702679  C   A   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   ['Solyc00g005000.3.1']  
SL3.0ch00   715124  G   A   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   ['Solyc00g005040.3.1']  
SL3.0ch00   723860  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS NONSYNONYMOUS   W/G 52  0   novel   DELETERIOUS (*WARNING! Low confidence)  ['Solyc00g005060.1.1', 'Solyc00g005080.2.1']    
SL3.0ch00   723867  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS SYNONYMOUS  G/G 49  1   novel   TOLERATED   ['Solyc00g005060.1.1', 'Solyc00g005080.2.1']    
SL3.0ch00   723903  T   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS SYNONYMOUS  G/G 37  1   novel   TOLERATED   ['Solyc00g005060.1.1']
```

Comment: Reading the entire huge file into memory just so you can loop over one line at a time is certainly an antipattern which should be easy to fix here.  Similarly you are looping over `loc_id` and processing the lines into a structure and then throwing it away, and do the same work again on the next iteration.

Comment: Is the second record in the desired output an error (`SL3.0ch00 715124 ...`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a start for GNU awk that matches the chromosome numbers and the position in the range:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$2][$3 " " $4]=$0                     # store the annotations
    next
}
($1 in a){                                  # if chromosome found
    for(i in a[$1])                         # process all the ranges
        if(split(i,t)&&$2>=t[1]&&$2<=t[2])  # if there is a match
            print                           # output
}' anno vari
```

Output atm:

```
SL3.0ch02   702679  C   A   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
SL3.0ch00   723860  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS     NONSYNONYMOUS   W/G     52  0   novel   DELETERIOUS (*WARNING! Low confidence)
SL3.0ch00   723860  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS     NONSYNONYMOUS   W/G     52  0   novel   DELETERIOUS (*WARNING! Low confidence)
SL3.0ch00   723867  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS     SYNONYMOUS  G/G     49  1   novel   TOLERATED
SL3.0ch00   723867  A   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS     SYNONYMOUS  G/G     49  1   novel   TOLERATED
SL3.0ch00   723903  T   C   Solyc00g005060.1    CDS     SYNONYMOUS  G/G     37  1   novel   TOLERATED
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be efficient to pre-process "annotation.txt" and create a dictionary in advance to reduce calculations in the loop.
Please try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
file1 = open("variation.txt", "r")
file2 = open("annotation.txt", "r")
probe_id = file1.read().splitlines()
loc_id = file2.read().splitlines()
annotation = {}

for i in loc_id:
    loc_info=i.split('\t')
    gene = loc_info[0].strip()
    chromosome = loc_info[1].strip()
    start = int(loc_info[2].strip())
    end = int(loc_info[3].strip())
    if (chromosome in annotation.keys()):
        annotation[chromosome].append([start, end, gene])
    else:
        annotation[chromosome] = [[start, end, gene]]

for i in probe_id:
    i = i.rstrip()
    probe_info = i.split('\t')
    position = int(probe_info[1].strip())
    chromosome = probe_info[0].strip()

    if (chromosome in annotation.keys()):
        for j in annotation[chromosome]:
            if (j[0] <= position and position <= j[1]):
                print i + '\t' + j[2]
```

The output:

```
SL3.0ch02   702679  C       A       -       -       -       -       -       -       -       -       Solyc00g005000.3.1
SL3.0ch00   723860  A       C       Solyc00g005060.1        CDS     NONSYNONYMOUS   W/G     52      0       novel   DELETERIOUS    (*WARNING!      Low     confidence)     Solyc00g005060.1.1
SL3.0ch00   723860  A       C       Solyc00g005060.1        CDS     NONSYNONYMOUS   W/G     52      0       novel   DELETERIOUS    (*WARNING!      Low     confidence)     Solyc00g005080.2.1
SL3.0ch00   723867  A       C       Solyc00g005060.1        CDS     SYNONYMOUS      G/G     49      1       novel   TOLERATED       Solyc00g005060.1.1
SL3.0ch00   723867  A       C       Solyc00g005060.1        CDS     SYNONYMOUS      G/G     49      1       novel   TOLERATED       Solyc00g005080.2.1
SL3.0ch00   723903  T       C       Solyc00g005060.1        CDS     SYNONYMOUS      G/G     37      1       novel   TOLERATED       Solyc00g005060.1.1
```

I suppose the algorithm is mostly close to @James Brown's answer.
Hope this helps.